# How do I turn off the touchpad gestures on VLC player in Ubuntu?

Tags: vlc

I looked under Tools, Preferences and mouse gestures are turned off but in reality they are not.
Is there any command line command I can enter to turn these off for VLC player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VLC, under tools->preferences, if you click on "Show settings - All" in the bottom left corner, you can access

[image]

Would this help with your gestures issue?